# Python: referencing previous self

Tags: python-3.x

i want to reference the previous self when summing a series.  For example, i have the following dataframe series:

```
a = [2,5,7,8,3,5,9]
```

I want to create a running sum of a (let's call this new series "b"), that references the previous item:

```
b = [0, 0+2, ((0+2)+5), ((0+2)+5)+7, ...]
```

I'm using a loop to do this:

```
b=0
for i in range (len(a)):
    b_temp=b[i-1]+a[i]
    b.append(b_temp)
```

I get the error msg:

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An integer is just a value, it doesn't retain any knowledge about the expression that produced the value.

Comment: If you're not too attached to writing your own code to solve this problem, the most Pythonic way is probably to call `itertools.accumulate`. It won't give you the leading `0` in the output, but should get the rest right.

Comment: how does itertools.accumulate work?

Answer (score 1):

i suppose this is the implementation u are looking for

```
b=[0]
a=[2,5,7,8,3,5,9]
for i in range (len(a)-1):
    if i-1>=0:
        u=b[i-1]
    else:
        u=0
    b_temp=u+a[i]
    b.append(b_temp)
print (b)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 2, 7, 14, 22, 25, 30]
```

The problem with your code was that it if u initialised b to 0,it becomes an integer and

then called `b[i-1]` it is not subscriptable because it is not a `list` it is an `integer` u can create a list for b by putting `b=[]`

Answer (score 0):

The error means The object is like lists or dictionaries and not the integer variable Hence it is not subscriptable.

So you need to define a list such as b = [ ]

And create a variable to store the sum of the variables which you can later append to the list object.

for code reference, you can refer this link
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/149379/pythonic-way-to-add-each-previous-element-in-list

Answer (score -1):

Because you set `b=0`, `b` is not a list or dataframe, it's an int. As such, it's not subscriptable. Maybe you want `b=[0]`?

(Besides that point, since `i` is 0 for your first iteration, you'll be looking for `b[-1]`, which will in fact work, but probably not for the reason you intend it to).